# Saving map as image using MapCanvas in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3, pdf, qgsmapcanvas

I have created a standalone application to display the vector layer using PyQGIS code given below. Now I want to download the map which shows on the window with whatever the zoom level I have chosen.

```py
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QMainWindow
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt

class MyWnd(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, layer):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

    self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
    self.canvas.setLayers([layer])

    self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

    self.actionZoomIn = QAction("Zoom in", self)
    self.actionZoomOut = QAction("Zoom out", self)
    self.actionPan = QAction("Pan", self)

    self.actionZoomIn.setCheckable(True)
    self.actionZoomOut.setCheckable(True)
    self.actionPan.setCheckable(True)

    self.actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)
    self.actionZoomOut.triggered.connect(self.zoomOut)
    self.actionPan.triggered.connect(self.pan)

    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Canvas actions")
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomIn)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomOut)
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionPan)

    # create the map tools
    self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
    self.toolPan.setAction(self.actionPan)
    self.toolZoomIn = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, False) # false = in
    self.toolZoomIn.setAction(self.actionZoomIn)
    self.toolZoomOut = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, True) # true = out
    self.toolZoomOut.setAction(self.actionZoomOut)

    self.pan()

  def zoomIn(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomIn)

  def zoomOut(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomOut)

  def pan(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolPan)

w = MyWnd(iface.activeLayer())
w.show()
```

No idea how to provide a download option within this window.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz using QGIS 3.8.Thanks for ur reply. I have changed the import now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to save the map as image. This is a minimal solution.

Add these lines to `__init__` method:

```py
self.actionSaveAsImage = QAction("Save As Image", self)
self.actionSaveAsImage.triggered.connect(self.saveAsImage)
self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionSaveAsImage)
```

And add this as a new method to the class:  (change image path)

```py
def saveAsImage(self):
  self.canvas.saveAsImage("/path/to/image.png")
```

[image]